# Is there a technical term for a signed value where only the top bit is set?

Tags: binary, terminology, notation, twos-complement

In two's-complement notation, there's always an odd-man-out value to compensate for the 0/origin value that is conceptually neither positive nor negative.  We treat 0 as positive for the sake of pragmatism, and we treat its counterpart, which is a 1 in the top bit and 0 in the rest, as negative, but conceptually, they are both special values that have no sign, because in both cases, -v==v.

For instance, in a signed 32-bit value, this number might be represented in one of these based forms:

```
0b10000000000000000000000000000000
0x80000000
-2147483648
```

I've personally been using my own term for this odd value for a while, which I will share below as my own answer, and let you all decide whether it's worthy, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's already an accepted name for it.

I leave the rest to you...

---

Edit: On further research, I did find some sites claiming that "it is sometimes called *the weird number*", but these blurbs are consistently copied verbatim from a Wikipedia entry on two's complement notation, which itself only references a 2006 college research paper that's unavailable at the given location, but I found [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bb0c/adebe4d34887e2468e535fa09f8ed3bdf2bb.pdf), where it's only referred to in passing as such.  Wikipedia also references a single book, but that book's usage appears to be based on the text of the Wikipedia entry, which existed before the book was written.  I'm not convinced that anyone other than one University of Tokyo student ever called it "the weird number" *in practice*.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context, I might refer to it neutrally as ***the dead value*** or, if I'm feeling like anthropomorphizing it, I call it ***Death***.  I think of that lone top bit as a scythe of sorts.

I call it this for two reasons:

1. On the ring that is two's-complement notation, its counterpart is 0, which we commonly refer to as *the origin*.  One antonym for *origin* is *death*.
2. This particular value, being ambiguous as it is, tends to catch out a lot of programmers.  It is literally the *death* of a lot of unsuspecting algorithms.

When writing terse assembly, I tend to abbreviate it as just "D", for instance if I had a condition that was satisfied by all values greater that zero, *and* Death, I might call the flag "GZD".

Comment: My brain never leaves stuff like this alone, so when I realized that this question may never receive another specific answer and we might just be left with paxdiablo's mention of the C limits.h names and my own idea, I started thinking of other things to propose.  I only came up with one one idea other: the outpost value, on the notion that it's the furthest value away from the origin.  I've never actually used this, so I'm not going to post it as an answer, but if I never feel like anyone posted something I felt was suitable, I'm leaving it here as a reminder to myself to propose it later.

Comment: @Aiken Drum - Actually, not just one other idea, after all: a related idea would be just "the post", sort of a visualization of that lone final bit.  But again, never actually used it, so not putting it up as an answer at this point.

Comment: PS: Yes, I know this site isn't for proposing ideas ("primarily opinion-based" closure is ubiquitous).  If it comes to that, I'd go somewhere else.  I'm just leaving notes to myself, really, in case that happens.

Comment: Another note to self: "nadir" might be an intuitive name, at least if the other person knows what a nadir is.  Also maybe "antipode", but "nadir" rolls off of the tongue better.

Answer (score 0):

I simply call that the *minimum integer* or *minimum value*, since that is indeed what it is in two's complement.

It's also described that way in the C standard `limits.h` (and C++ equivalent) header, such as with `SCHAR_MIN`, `INT_MIN`, `LONG_MIN` and so on.

Comment: I agree that, for most general purposes, it does function as the minimum or most negative value.  Still, it's not a normal value, because, like 0, taking its negative gives you the same value.  In almost all math, 0 is given special status because of that unique property.  Only in two's complement notation do we have a complementary value, so I don't think most people have had the opportunity to think of it as special, until perhaps it bites them in the butt for the Nth time and they realize it isn't actually *just* a really low number.  I'm looking for a name given to it by people who have.

Comment: (honestly, it may be that only I and some U of Tokyo student ever thought about it  at all...)